# How to escape square closing bracket in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm parsing come legacy C-code using grep and sed and when trying to replace square brackets, something strange happened.

The following code to replace square opening brackets works fine:

`$ echo "xyx[xzx]xyx" | sed 's|[\[]| |g'`

results in:

`xyx xzx]xyx`

When I now add `\]` to the string to sed, to also replace square closing brackets, it stops working:

`$ echo "xyx[xzx]xyx" | sed 's|[\[\]]| |g'`

now results in:

`xyx[xzx]xyx`

As far as I know, this is the proper way to escape square brackets.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running this on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't even need to escape:

```
echo "xyx[xzx]xyx" | sed 's|[][]| |g'
xyx xzx xyx
```

However keep in mind that order of `]` then `[` is important here.

Comment: This is because if `]` is the first character in the character class, it doesn't need excaping, as in `[]abc]` or, as pictured, `[][]`

Comment: @anubhava I tried it and it works. Thanks. There however still remain 2 things nagging. 1. Why can I both use `[` and `\[` to represent the square opening bracket and 2. How to include both `]` and `-` in a character class.

Comment: @Geert The answer to the first nagging issue is simple: A backslash is not a special character inside a character class. The sequence `\[` represents both characters.

Comment: For replacing `-` with `[` and `]` you can use: `echo "xyx[xzx]xyx-abc" | sed 's|[][-]| |g'`

Comment: I still can't undestand why `[[]]` is treated differently than `[][]`?

Comment: @Hergott `[[]]` is interpreted as `[[]` (match any of the one-character list `[`) followed by `]`.

Comment: It will find both `[` and `]`

Comment: Okay, but `echo "xyx[xzx]xyx" | sed 's|[][]| |g'` actually does work. So how can this be explained? The answer doesn't shine light on that.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I'm stupid: '[][]' is of course a group (enclosed with '[' and ']), containing ']' and '['.